# SSRS show field names in textbox expressions

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

I have a simple SSRS report that uses one dataset.  However, the report layout is not and cannot be in a table format. Since I don't have a table, all my textbox expressions are lookups instead of just the field name.  How can I set up the report so the dataset field names show in the textbox without having a table?

I've tried:
Looking for a report-wide dataset property.   No luck.
Creating a table with one row/column the size of the report to paste everything into.  No luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you mean you want to see the field name in the textbox in the design view, instead of <Expr> then I'm not sure you will be able to do this as designer will only show a field name if the value expression is just a field name and nothing else.

Comment: It does it if the textbox is part of a table that has a dataset.  I'm trying to do it without a table.  Thank you, though.

Comment: Can you just add another textbox above it and manually type the field name?

Comment: Just typing a filed name doesn't do anything.  The textbox has to be associated with a dataset somehow.  But my layout won't work inside a table so I can't do it that way.  I thought I could put multiple controls into one row both horizontally and vertically, but alas... no. Looking for a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is so important as it's only seen in the designer but I guess it is to you....

The only way I know of getting close to this is to use a table and then either

Add rows and columns to support your layout, set individual cells to whatever fields you want.

or

Use a table bound to your dataset with just a single cell (or a few more if it makes the layout easier) and then insert placeholders into the cell(s), you can mix text in with these too.

Here's an example in design mode using just one textbox

[image]

To add the placeholders, right click on the cell and then "create placeholder", then right-click the placeholder and select the field from the drop down list under 'value'.

**Note:** You can't place these freely within the cell, they are inserted into or appended to text strings so you might have to pad the spacing out with blanks. I would suggest using a monospaced for for this to ensure consistency.

As you can see the placeholder for account number has been formatted as has the word 'text' so you still have quite a lot of control.

When the report runs (with just 1 record) we get this

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about the placeholders.  This is about as close as you can get.  I miss Access reports.  I do have fields that aren't always labeled so it's nice to have a visual to see what's there..